# Access VBA code to import emails into table

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, outlook, office-automation

I have inherited a database which has VBA code, unfortunately the colleague has left the organisation and we need to make 4 amendments.  1 - The code works on your personal inbox however we have moved to a team mailbox, so can anyone assist with how to change the code to address this?  2 - We need to pull the senders email address currently it pulls the persons name on occasion it will identify an email but that is very limited (is it to do with the SMTP address?)  3 - we would like to put a date range for the pulling of emails.  4- Once it has imported the emails can it move them to a folder called imported.

Thanks

```
Sub ImportMailPropFromOutlook()

    ' Code for specifing top level folder and initializing routine.

    ' Set up Outlook objects.
    Dim ol As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim ofO As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim ofSubO As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items

    Set olns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set ofO = olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) '--- Specifies top level folder for     importing Oultook mail.
    'Set of = olns.PickFolder '--- Allows user to select top level folder for importing     Outlook mail.

    'Set info and call GetMailProp code.
    Set objItems = ofO.Items
    GetMailProp objItems, ofO

    'Set info and call ProcessSubFolders.
    'For Each ofSubO In of.Folders
    '    Set objItems = ofSubO.Items
    '    ProcessSubFolders objItems, ofSubO
    'Next

End Sub

Sub GetMailProp(objProp As Outlook.Items, ofProp As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

    ' Code for writeing Outlook mail properties to Access.

    ' Set up DAO objects (uses existing Access "Email" table).
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Email")

    'Set Up Outlook objects.
    Dim cMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim cAtch As Outlook.Attachments

    'Write Outlook mail properties to Access "Email" table.
    iNumMessages = objProp.Count
    If iNumMessages <> 0 Then
        For i = 1 To iNumMessages
            If TypeName(objProp(i)) = "MailItem" Then
                Set cMail = objProp(i)
                'If ([rst]![EmailLocation] <> ofProp.Name) And ([rst]![EntryID] <> cMail.EntryID) Then
                    rst.AddNew
                    rst!EntryID = cMail.EntryID
                    rst!ConversationID = cMail.ConversationID
                    rst!Sender = cMail.Sender
                    rst!SenderName = cMail.SenderName
                    rst!SentOn = cMail.SentOn
                    rst!To = cMail.To
                    rst!CC = cMail.CC
                    rst!BCC = cMail.BCC
                    rst!Subject = cMail.Subject
                    Set cAtch = cMail.Attachments
                    cntAtch = cAtch.Count
                    If cntAtch > 0 Then
                        For j = cntAtch To 1 Step -1
                            strAtch = cAtch.Item(j).FileName
                            rst!Attachments = strAtch
                        Next
                    Else
                        rst!Attachments = "No Attachments"
                    End If
                    'rst!Count = cMail.Attachments.Count
                    rst!Body = cMail.Body
                    rst!HTMLBody = cMail.HTMLBody
                    rst!Importance = cMail.Importance
                    rst!Size = cMail.Size
                    rst!CreationTime = cMail.CreationTime
                    rst!ReceivedTime = cMail.ReceivedTime
                    rst!ExpiryTime = cMail.ExpiryTime
                    'rst!EmailLocation = ofProp.Name
                    rst.Update
                'End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

End Sub

Sub ProcessSubFolders(objItemsR As Outlook.Items, OfR As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

    'Code for processing subfolders

    ' Set up Outlook objects.
    Dim ofSubR As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    'Set info and call GetMailProp code.
    GetMailProp objItemsR, OfR

    'Set info and call ProcessSubFolders. Recursive.
    For Each ofSubR In OfR.Folders
        Set objItemsR = ofSubR.Items
        ProcessSubFolders objItemsR, ofSubR
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You may find the site more useful as a place to search for answers to previously asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "Before posting a question, we strongly recommend that you spend a reasonable amount of time researching the problem and searching for existing questions on this site that may provide an answer. (Stack Overflow has been around for a long time now, so many common questions have already been answered.)"

Answer (score 1):

> We need to pull the senders email address currently it pulls the persons name on occasion it will identify an email but that is very limited (is it to do with the SMTP address?)

In the code you are getting the [Sender](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.sender) property, but it is not a scalar property. it returns an instance of the an [AddressEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry) object that corresponds to the user of the account from which the `MailItem` is sent. Instead, you need to use the [Address](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.address) property of the `AddressEntry` class to get a string representing the email address.

In case of Exchange accounts you may use the [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getexchangeuser) method which returns an `ExchangeUser` object that represents the `AddressEntry` if the `AddressEntry` belongs to an Exchange `AddressList` object such as the Global Address List (GAL) and corresponds to an Exchange user. Then you may get the [ExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser.primarysmtpaddress) property value which is a string representing the primary Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) address for the `ExchangeUser`. Returns an empty string if this property has not been implemented or does not exist for the `ExchangeUser` object.

In cases when you need to convert Ex-like addresses to SMTP ones you may find the [HowTo: Convert Exchange-based email address into SMTP email address](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2009/05/08/outlook-exchange-email-address-smtp/) article helpful.

> Once it has imported the emails can it move them to a folder called imported.

Use the [Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) method available for all Outlook items.